# How to store multiple foreign key values in a single field?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, primary-key

I have following two tables in an **MS SQL-Server** Database:

```
user_info
  ( user_id PRIMARY KEY, 
    email, 
    password
  )
```

and

```
messages
  ( time_stamp, 
    message, 
    sender, 
    recipients, 
    FOREIGN KEY(sender) 
      REFERENCES user_info (user_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(recipients) 
      REFERENCES user_info (user_id)
  )
```

I am wondering if it is possible to store multiple `user_id` values in the recipients field of `messages` table. I am a newbie, please help me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a one-to-many relationship `message_recipients` table.

```
user_info
( 
  user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  email VARCHAR(256), 
  password VARCHAR(256)
);

messages
( 
  message_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  time_stamp DATETIME, 
  message VARCHAR(4000), 
  sender INTEGER -- references user_info.user_id
);

message_recipients
(
  message_id INTEGER, -- references messages.message_id
  recipient_id INTEGER -- references user_info.user_id
);
```

Comment: what if I make `message_id` and `recipient_id` as composite primary key?

Comment: @MAKhan do you mean on the message_recipients table? As long as the same recipient can't be on the same message twice that would be a good constraint.